# can I apply Recursive Feature Elimination method with mixed data set ( numeric, categorical features)?

Tags: machine-learning

Recursive Feature Elimination is a way to choose features. my question is can I apply this method to the mixed dataset ( numeric, categorical features)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes -- as long as you can provide a standard or custom evaluation of the appropriate characteristics (e.g. cross-correlation), RFE will work on any data.  You may have to do some experimentation to determine how you want to correlate numeric vs categorical data, but there's certainly nothing to stop you from finding those relationships.